# Can Pester Mock [Type]::new()

Tags: powershell, pester

I have script that has the following code:

```
 $var1 = [TESTType]::new($Var)
```

I would like to run a pester test that Mock [TESTType]::new($Var).
Is This possible ?

Comment: `Mock` won't be able to, but in PowerShell >6 you could add a `class TESTType` definition in the test fixture and it should take precedence over any existing custom classes

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a wrapper function. You could for example do this:

```bsh
function Get-TESTType {
    param(
    [Parameter()]$ContructorVar
    )
    return [TESTType]::new($ConstructorVar)
}
```

Then you can mock this function

```bsh
It "Mocks the TESTType Class" {
    Mock Get-TESTType {
        @{
            field1 = 'something'
            field2 = 'something'
        }
    }
    # Put your test here
}
```

Comment: Just happened to stumble across this while looking for something else. Might be worth looking into instead:
https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/New-MockObject

Comment: Believe New-MockObject is simply for creating a mock object to then pass into the function. Whereas here you're attempting to mock ::new() inside the function you're trying to test.